# Debug an app on Chrome-OS device using Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, chromebook

**tldr**:
I have an Acer Chromebook laptop which can also be used as a tablet. Can I connect it to my Mac as a device for Android Studio?

**Detailed version**:
I have a Mac on which I've installed Android Studio for developing Android and Chrome-OS applications. I want to debug an app for chrome-os, but not on the emulator, but on a real device. Can I connect the Acer Chromebook to my Mac for debugging (it's possible to connect Android phone to the Mac, but I don't know about Chrome-OS devices).

If it's not possible, what's the best way to debug an app the that specific device?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Chrome OS Systems Supporting ADB Debugging over USB](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-adb-debugging-over-usb). It's not something I've ever tried myself.

Comment: My Chromebook model isn't supported, but I used debugging over WIFI.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: You could answer it yourself as you are more familiar with the topic. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

The ways to debug apps on Chromebook from another device are debugging via USB or debugging via WIFI.